# Stage Resize Event (JavaFX)

Tags: events, javafx, resize

I just started programming with JavaFX and SceneBuilder and I need my window to always have the same width-height proportion. Since I worked with swing before, I thought about an Event for every time the window resizes so I can edit the width/height at the same time but I didn‘t find an opportunity for such an event yet.

I hope anybody of you understands my problem and has an idea to solve it :)

Comment: Stage has a `widthProperty()` and a `heightProperty()` with which you can register listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @James_D mentioned in the comment, there's `widthProperty()` and `heightProperty()` with which you can register listeners. Here's a simple coding example for that

```
   private void stageSizeChageListener(Stage stage){
        stage.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println("Width changed!!");
            }
        });

        stage.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                System.out.println("Height changed!!");
            }
        });


    }
```